# EditText cannot be edited when SetOnTouchListener is added

Tags: android, android-edittext

i have place edittext inside a fragment and i also add a SetOnTouchListener for that edittext so that the app know the number of a letter that the user clicked. the problem is that now i cannot edit the edittext anymore. i had no idea why please help. The EditText is inside a Fragment and it only show up when the method are clicked

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
    private Context context;
    private ExpandableListView expandableListView;
    public com.onedevz.noct.Adapters.ExpandableListAdapter expandableListAdapter;
    private List<String> expandableListTitle;
    public  HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail;
    private View view;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ViewGroup mContainer;
    public  EditText editText;
    public  Button button;

    HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetailz = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    List<String> title = new ArrayList<>();
    public MainFragment(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mInflater = inflater;
        mContainer = container;


        return showExpand();
    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    public View showNotes(){
        mContainer.removeAllViews();
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.contentsingle,mContainer,false);
        button = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.returnButton);
        editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.ContentText);
        button.setText("< return");
        editText.setText("");
        editText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    Layout layout = ((TextView) v).getLayout();
                    int x = (int)event.getX();
                    int y = (int)event.getY();
                    if (layout!=null){
                        int line = layout.getLineForVertical(y);
                        int offset = layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(line, x);
                        try{
                            char texts = editText.getText().charAt(offset);
                            Toast.makeText(context,"the offset are "+offset+"letter are "+texts,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }catch (Exception e){
                            Toast.makeText(context,"the error are "+e,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
        mContainer.addView(view);
        return view;
    }
    public View showNote(){
        mContainer.removeAllViews();
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.contentexpand,mContainer,false);
        expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.expandablelistview);
        expandableListDetail = ExpandListData.getData();
        expandableListTitle = new ArrayList<>( expandableListDetail.keySet() );
        expandableListAdapter = new com.onedevz.noct.Adapters.ExpandableListAdapter( context,expandableListTitle,expandableListDetail );
        expandableListView.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);
        expandableListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        expandables();
        mContainer.addView(view);
        return view;
    }

    public View showNote2(){
        mContainer.removeAllViews();
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.contentexpand,mContainer,false);
        expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.expandablelistview);
        title.add( "Great" );
        expandableListDetailz.put( "wow",title );
        expandableListDetail = expandableListDetailz;
        expandableListTitle = new ArrayList<>( expandableListDetail.keySet() );
        expandableListAdapter = new com.onedevz.noct.Adapters.ExpandableListAdapter( context,expandableListTitle,expandableListDetail );
        expandableListView.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);
        expandableListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        expandables();
        mContainer.addView(view);
        return view;
    }

    public void showNote3(){
        title.add( "new note" );
    }
    public View showCalendar(){
        mContainer.removeAllViews();
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.contentdouble,mContainer,false);
        expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.ExpandableCalendarTask);
        expandableListDetail = ExpandListData.getData();
        expandableListTitle = new ArrayList<>( expandableListDetail.keySet() );
        expandableListAdapter = new com.onedevz.noct.Adapters.ExpandableListAdapter( context,expandableListTitle,expandableListDetail );
        expandableListView.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);
        expandableListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        expandables();
        mContainer.addView(view);
        return view;
    }

    public View showSocial(){
        mContainer.removeAllViews();
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.contentwebview,mContainer,false);
        WebView webView = (WebView)view.findViewById( R.id.webview );
        webView.setWebViewClient( new WebViewClient() );
        webView.loadUrl( "http://www.facebook.com" );
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mContainer.addView(view);
        return view;
    }

    public View showExpand(){
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.contentexpand,mContainer,false);
        expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.expandablelistview);
        expandableListDetail = ExpandListData.getData();
        expandableListTitle = new ArrayList<>( expandableListDetail.keySet() );
        expandableListAdapter = new com.onedevz.noct.Adapters.ExpandableListAdapter( context,expandableListTitle,expandableListDetail );
        expandableListView.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);
        expandableListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        expandables();
        return view;
    }
    public void expandables(){
        expandableListView.setOnGroupClickListener( new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
                Log.v( "expand","i am clicked"+groupPosition );
                return false;
            }
        } );
        expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener( new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                String country = (String)expandableListAdapter.getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
                Log.v( "i am at group"+groupPosition,"row at "+country );
                Toast.makeText( context,"i am at"+childPosition,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                return true;
            }
        } );
    }


}
```

Comment: Try return `false` in `onTouch` method

Comment: btw, i dont really get it why it wont let met edit when i return true. how does it exatcly work? can you please explain it to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From: Offical documentation [View.OnTouchListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html#onTouch(android.view.View,%20android.view.MotionEvent))

> **onTouch**
>   Returns: boolean
>
> True if the listener has consumed the event, false otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Try that,

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    doSomething();
}
```

});